# Should I approve the edits with very little changes?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Refer this:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17189091

Points to note:

- Original post is good enough to understand the contents.
- There are very little changes in suggested edit. Those does not improve the post considerably.
- Original post is very old and received many up votes; proves that others are able to understand the contents.
- I only notice one change (out of other three): 'ontop' changed to 'on top'. Other changes does not make much sense.

Look at this other example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17189506

Here, only "Thanks" is removed.

Should I approve this edit just for one very minor edit?

What should be the Do's and Dont's while Accepting/Rejecting Suggested Edits.

Comment: In the first case, do you see any other changes that needed to be made that the reviewer missed? Me neither.

Comment: In the second one, they didn't even remove the "Thanks", they just removed the user's name and put "Thanks" on its own line.

Comment: No; I don't see any other change necessary which will considerably improve the post.

Comment: "Original post is good enough to understand the contents" there's never a post "good enough". We want them to be the best.

Comment: Why should it be just good enough to understand?  Surely "a local branches" is bad English which is corrected in the proposed edit to "a local branch"? (first post)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my opinion the first edit should have been accepted.

> for a local branches

Is not correct.  The editor changed it to

> for a local branch

which is an improvement.  They also added a space between

> `--soft`reset

which needs to be there.

There is no too minor reject reason; we got rid of that.  If the edit improves what can be improved, even if that is only a little bit, it should be approved.  You can't take its age or votes into consideration.  I have seen posts that had a typo in them that had been seen thousands of times and voted on hundreds of times.

In your second example the thanks is not needed so the editor didn't improve everything that could be improved.  Typically I'll reject and edit those so the editor can see what the full edit should have been.

Comment: Any suggestion about second post in question?

Comment: @AmitJoshi should be improved to remove the whole "thanks, user x" and not just the username _(Which has now already been done)_

Comment: @AmitJoshi I just added that into the answer

Comment: I totally agree - it should have been accepted!

Answer (score 8):

I would have accepted the first edit. Each of the changes does improve the post, does not change the meaning, and I can't see any other obvious changes that need to be made. The age of the post or its popularity shouldn't be a factor. If it can be improved, go ahead and approve the edit.

In the second case, I would have rejected the edit and just removed the "thanks" altogether instead of modifying it. I'm not sure if that question is "too broad" or not, so even removing the "thanks" is probably not enough to salvage it.